# How to add method to Route class in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, object, inheritance

I try to add a custom method to the **Route class** (not Router) on laravel 5.3.

```
Route::get('/search', 'Search@index')->localize();
```

If i write localize methode directly in \Illuminate\Routing\Router it will work, but it's ugly...

How can i extend the \Illuminate\Routing\Router Class to add my custom method ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: What is localize() supposed to do? I don't think you're supposed to add methods to the existing route. If you tell us what it's supposed to do then there might be a better alternative :-)

Comment: Localize() it supposed to do something like that : 

`Route::get('/{search}', 'Search@index')->where('search', '(rechercher|search-item)');`

It will convert the "default route" with values coming from database. 
Allowing multi language routes, without prefix like /en/